How to read the SAML response returned by IdP
I am trying to figure out how to get an email from the saml2AuthnResponse that is returned by the IdP.
I am not sure how to access this using ITFoxTec.
Here is my AssertionConsumerService code:
[Route("AssertionConsumerService")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AssertionConsumerService()
{
    var binding = new Saml2PostBinding();
    var saml2AuthnResponse = new Saml2AuthnResponse(config);

    binding.ReadSamlResponse(Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(validate: true), saml2AuthnResponse);
    if (saml2AuthnResponse.Status != Saml2StatusCodes.Success)
    {
        throw new AuthenticationException($"SAML Response status: {saml2AuthnResponse.Status}");
    }
    binding.Unbind(Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(validate: true), saml2AuthnResponse);
    await saml2AuthnResponse.CreateSession(HttpContext, claimsTransform: (claimsPrincipal) => ClaimsTransform.Transform(claimsPrincipal));

    var relayStateQuery = binding.GetRelayStateQuery();
    var returnUrl = relayStateQuery.ContainsKey(relayStateReturnUrl) ? relayStateQuery[relayStateReturnUrl] : Url.Content("~/na");

    // local custom login service
    var username = saml2AuthnResponse.NameId;
    var user = _loginService.Login(username.ToString(), null);
    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(user);

    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}

I know it's being sent by the IdP, because when I examine the output of a SAML browser extension, I can see it...here is an example:
    <saml2:Attribute FriendlyName="eduPersonPrincipalName"
                     Name="urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.5923.1.1.1.6"                          
                     NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri"
    >   
   
        <saml2:AttributeValue>Aaron.Andrews92@sot.gov</saml2:AttributeValue>

    </saml2:Attribute>
</saml2:AttributeStatement>
</saml2:Assertion>
</saml2p:Response>

Is there a way to do this?
Thanks!

You can show respect for those who might help you by making the minimal effort to ensure your code samples are formatted properly, with good indentation.

Thanks @JoelCoehoorn, I appreciate the edit.

I've only used the ItFoxTec library once and haven't had to do this myself yet, but from what I can see in the working code I'm using you need to look at saml2AuthnResponse.ClaimsIdentity

Additionally, it can be possible in some rare scenarios for some IdPs to return a successful response for an unauthenticated user. So where you have this code:
if (saml2AuthnResponse.Status != Saml2StatusCodes.Success)

my own system looks like this:
if (saml2AuthnResponse.Status != Saml2StatusCodes.Success || ! saml2AuthnResponse.ClaimsIdentity.IsAuthenticated)

Of course there are more ways to do it, but that second check is important.
